# Date Filtering in Responsive Datatable extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to filter records in table with user defined start-date and end-date. Its working fine by using simple datatables: 
https://datatables.net/plug-ins/filtering/row-based/range_dates

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    var iFini = document.getElementById('fini').value;
    var iFfin = document.getElementById('ffin').value;
    var iStartDateCol = 6;
    var iEndDateCol = 7;

    iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);
    iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2);

    var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
    var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

    if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

);

However my problem is to have it working with responsive data tables:
        https://editor.datatables.net/examples/extensions/responsive.html

Now It would be quit a help if someone get me through with it. I tried different combinations

```
   $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.afnFiltering.push
```

But I don't think these functions exists.

Thanks,
Kashif

Comment: have you made sure that the responsive libs were included? https://datatables.net/download/release